# What sci fi movie was set in a cavern & dealt with electricity generation?

Tags: story-identification, movie

What sci fi movie (could have been a "TV" movie) was set in a cavern & dealt with electricity generation?

The struggle in the movie was "cowboy inventor dude" vs "evil corporation".  Protagonist is a Robert Redford like dude maybe?.?

It might have had something to do with the sonic properties of the cavern harmonics?.?

I believe there might have been some large "Tesla coil" style lightning special effects during the destruction of the invention (but I could be conflating different movies together.)

Maybe in the 80's?.?  (or late 70's / early 90's)?

Thanks!

Comment: Not the power generation segment of *Forbidden Planet*?

Comment: @Lexible thanks for your suggestion, I checked it out; but it wasn't that old (or that movie.)

Comment: @Lexible I doubt that the machines of Altair IV generated anything so mundane as electricity. That does not mean the OP was not thinking of the movie. But if u asked a scifi author about how an advanced alien civilization generated power I bet they would come up with something like getting it from a mini black hole and maybe transmitted via quarks or something.

Comment: This sounds a bit like "The Old Man in the Cave" episode of the Twilight Zone from 1963. The gist of the episode is that the town follows messages from the "old man" in a nearby cave. Spoilers: it is revealed to be a computer. The Robert Redford like dude might be the episode's antagonist played by James Coburn. The machine is destroyed and there are lightning and explosion effects.

Comment: @Cassfrank thanks for the comment, it took me a while to get a copy to watch; and while I truly enjoyed the episode, it's not what I was looking for (I'm pretty sure it was 'newer' & in color )

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like part of "A Connecticut Yankee in King Arthur's Court", by Mark Twain.

I don't think the Bing Crosby movie included the electrical generation part of the novel, but perhaps there was a later version that did.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  While this does suggest a possible source for the scene, can you find any movie that included it?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but alas this movie was made much later; & from what I can tell the central theme wasn't the same.